# Find all parameters $a$ , $b$ such that a polynomial $f ( x ) = x ^ 3 + ax ^ 2 + bx$ has exactly one tangent that passes through the origin .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, tangent-line

Determine all parameters $a$ and $b$ such that a polynomial given by $f ( x ) = x ^ 3 + ax ^ 2 + bx$ has exactly one tangent that passes through the origin .

My work:
Let use equation for tangent line:

$y-y_0=y'(x_0)(x-x_0)$. We know that $x=y=0$ because tangent line pass through  $(0,0)$(origin).

$y_0=y'(x_0)*x_0$. Next we need to find derivative of $y$.

$y'(x_0)=3x_0^2+2ax_0+b$

 Our eqation of tangent line now look like this.

$$y_0=(3x_0^2+2ax_0+b)x_0$$
$$x_0^3+ax_0^2+bx_0=3x_0^3+2ax_0^2+bx_0$$
$$2x_0^3+ax_0^2=0$$
$$x_0^2(2x_0+a)=0$$
Or $x_0=0$ or $a=-2x_0$
But I'am not sure how to finish my work.

Comment: Since $f(0)=0$, you know that the tangent at $x=0$ passes through the origin. You need to make sure that none others do. You’ve derived a condition for the tangent at $(x_0,f(x_0))$ to pass through the origin so... ?

Comment: You have shown that the tangent at $x=0$ passes through the origin iff $x_0=-\frac{a}{2}$ or $x=0$. So what does that tell you about the number of tangents that pass through the origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given function always has a tangent at ${x_0} = 0$. Since we can choose any ${x_0}$ the point on f, (${x_0},f({x_0}$) is also a point on a tangent through the origin when $a =  - 2{x_0}$.

The ordinate of this point, for any value, $b$, is given by:$$x_0^3 - 2{x_0}x_0^2 + b{x_0} =  - x_0^3 + b{x_0}.$$

A dynamic sketch of the situation can be seen at Geogebra:

[Find All Parameters](http://ggbtu.be/meXX8aKEW)

Comment: @user328032 The GeoGebra example is terrific.